# Magento2 - How to add a new section to customer account page

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I want to add a new section with my own links to the customer account page (see pic) This section should be visible based on my custom extension of the customer entity.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Create your own extension.
Let's call it `StackExchange_Customer`.
You will need these files:

`app/code/StackExchange/Customer/registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'StackExchange_Customer',
    __DIR__
);
```

`app/code/StackExchange/Customer/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="StackExchange_Customer" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

`app/code/StackExchange/Customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="account"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="customer_account_navigation_secondary" after="customer_account_navigation" template="Magento_Customer::account/navigation.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-account-link-secondary"> <!-- duplicate this as many times as you need, just make sure the name is unique -->
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Some link here</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">module/controller/action</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

then run in the console `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

Comment: you didn't explain the controller part 'module/controller/action' what should it be? 'customer/account/custom' ?

What class should that controller extend if so? etc

Comment: because there was no requirement for the controller action. I just explained how to add a link. I assumed the OP knows how to create a controller

Comment: Hi @Marius how to include all links under one link, means toggle dropdown in magento2

Comment: @Marius Hey !
I use your answer but there is no effect . no any tab show in customer account section

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: yes dear it not work :(

Comment: @Marius your answer perfect . it was my mistake i solved . But Css not applied . 
It show simple side bar . How can give same look as magento defauld side have look . please update your answer how can add bootstrap or custom css class add and use in `customer_account.xml` .
Thank you