# Magento 2.1 add a new section on my account page

Tags: magento-2.1, module, customer-account

I need to add a custom tab at bottom of left menu on my account page 'link 1' and add a corresponding template file so that I can display my custom forms and dynamic custom content for that user.

**I have tried the following**:

This one doesn't works:
http://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/magento-technical-notes-60/post/add-custom-tab-on-customer-account-section-in-magento-2-317

This one works but the links are not having template files:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/100096/39707

On customer page:

You can see my blog is displaying

[image]

After you click on 'My Blog': It takes to 404

[image]

Following is the complete module code:

Namespace/Support/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-suppport-ticket-link" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">support/customer/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Support Ticket</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Namespace/Support/view/frontend/layout/support_customer_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <head>
        <title>Support Ticket</title>
        <css src="Namespace_Support::css/styles.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Namespace\Support\Block\TicketList" name="ticketViewList" template="Namespace_Support::list.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Namespace/Support/view/frontend/templates/list.phtml

```
<?php echo 'hello' ;?>
```

Namespace/Support/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_Support" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Namespace/Support/Controller/Customer/index.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Support\Controller\Customer;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Namespace\Support\Controller\Index
{
    /**
     * Show customer tickets
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     * @throws NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_PAGE);
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Namespace/Support/Block/TicketList/index.php

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Support\Block\TicketList;


class TicketList extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, array $data = []) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }


    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```

Namespace/Support/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Namespace_Support',
    __DIR__
);
```

Please guide me to achieve my task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112178/add-custom-active-links-to-customer-account-navigation-in-magento-2

Comment: Is custom link showing or not?

Comment: @Magento2Learner: no its not. For first link nothing is working and for second only custom links are being displayed on myaccount page but it do not have any phtml template.

Comment: It would be better that you share some of code so exact problem can be identified.

Comment: Show me customer_account.xml file code and what is your custom module name?

Comment: @Magento2Learner: I have updated my question with entire code.

Comment: @WasiqShahrukh as mentioned by Suresh Chikani you need to add routes.xml file.

Comment: @WasiqShahrukh Have you try my answer solution?

Comment: @WasiqShahrukh Accept my answer if it is useful for you.

Comment: @SureshChikani It is not working, instead 'There has been an error processing your request'. I have added comment to your answer with corresponding report file.

Comment: Error is not related to this code. It's related to UI component. Please check it with developer mode.

Comment: @SureshChikani I developer mode it says: invalid block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `routes.xml` file in your module.
You need to create `routes.xml` file with below code

**app/code/Namespace/Support/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="support" frontName="support">
            <module name="Namespace_Support" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

You should also correct you block like this - Remove `TicketList` from block namespace

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Support\Block;


class TicketList extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, array $data = []) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }


    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```

Comment: It is now giving error page. [This](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sWwbYa_NtoHVl3GfIpVe6phDPkADyvtvfhhfBJ6T2S4/edit?usp=sharing) is the report file

Comment: First enable developer mode and check.

Comment: In Developer mode, I got following exception: '**2 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Namespace\Support\Block\TicketList Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Namespace\Support\Block\TicketList does not exist**'

Comment: Check my updated answer, You have to correct your block namespace and path.

Comment: Hi @SureshChikani How to add same links as dropdown under one link in magento2

Comment: Hi @SureshChikani any update on this?